# How does the Skywalker line get from Luke to Cade?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Essentially, Luke gives the Jedi Grandmaster title to Ben Skywalker at the end of *Crucible*. Then at 135(ish) ABY, Cade Skywalker is mentioned in the comics.

**Is there a family tree or something to show Cade's lineage back to Luke?**

Comment: Other than saying through Ben Skywalker - surely if such a family tree existed it would be in the wookiepedia archives.

Comment: I doubt any family tree exists. One of the reasons you put a hundred-year timeskip between storylines is to avoid having to worry about minutiae like that.

Comment: I fail to see why people are voting to close this **perfectly clear question** as unclear.

Comment: @Valorum the question is unclear because it refers to both the Grand Master title and the name Skywalker.  The question was `is there a family tree that shows how *it* went from Luke to Cade` - it is not specified which "it" are they asking about, there are two possibilities here.

Comment: @JK. - Sure, if you only read the body of the question and not the title which clears that right up for you

Comment: @JK. - I've edited it to make it ***abundantly clear*** what OP wants to ask.

Comment: @Valorum so if you edited it then you admit it was unclear, correct?  You have actually made clear the one sentence that contains the question.  However the first sentence which talks about Jedi titles, is not even relevant to the question in the slightest.  Fully 2/3 of the text of this post is not even part of the actual question.  So a close vote is still appropriate.

Comment: @JK. - So edited it because I thought it could be worded better, not because it was in any way unclear what OP was asking. In this instance the body is actually entirely redundant because the question title is so solid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character's co-creator [confirmed](https://boards.theforce.net/threads/legacy-comics-and-legacy-of-the-force-timing-issues-legacy-and-lotf-spoilers.25474459/#post-25480647) that Cade Skywalker is descended from Ben Skywalker (Ben being the son of Luke Skywalker and Mara Jade in Legends) and speculated that Cade is Luke's great-grandson, or possibly great-great-grandson.

The 'missing link' in this family tree is Ben's son. This individual doesn't appear to have been mentioned in any official works.

> Not official or accurate--and Cade's birthdate is spproximate there. I was just giving a 'for instance' in which the timeline with an 'unknown' Skywalker was feasible. Heck, if Ben and "Ben's son" father kids about the same age Anakin did, there could might even be another generation of Skywalkers in there somewhere...
>
> Ben 26.5 ABY
> Unknown 50 ABY
> Unknown 2 72 ABY
> Kol 94 ABY
> Cade 116 ABY

and

> Not sure why one more generation between Ben and Kol is problematic.
>
> Cade is 14 in 130 ABY and is around 21 in Legacy (136 ABY). So Cade was born around 115-16 ABY.
>
> So-- Ben is born in 26.5 ABY, which puts Luke at about 48 when he is born.
> If Ben were to have kids when he is, say, 35, that puts us at 61 ABY.
> Ben's son ? has a kid at about 30 (Kol?) and that puts us at 91 ABY.
> Kol's son Cade is born around 115-16 ABY. Kol would be 24.
>
> Summing up:
>
> Ben born 26.5 ABY (Luke is 48?)
> Ben's son born 61 ABY (Ben is 35?)
> Kol born 91 ABY (Ben's son is 30?)
> Cade born 115 ABY (Kol is 24.)
>
> Possible?